# Deploy flutter web to TOMCAT

Tags: flutter, web, tomcat, flutter-web

My requirement is to deploy flutter web application with a specific app name on tomcat. Can anyone please help me on this one. I have tried to modify the manifest.json by adding start_url, but it didn't work.

Comment: You cannot do this since Tomcat is a Java servlet container, Flutter can build a regular js file, not a servlet

Comment: Flutter doesn't create a [Java Web Application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/appdev/index.html), specifically not the directory structure that you need.  It can be done but what are your requirements with Tomcat vs Flutter?

Comment: @stdunbar, ok I got your point. I have tried and hosted the react ja application on tomcat so I thought flutter web will also work. I am trying to deploy the application to my Webmethods server. It's a tech related to integration. React js deployment has worked. I want to achieve he same with flutter web.

Comment: @YuriHeiko if in tomcat is not possible, then where to deploy the flutter web build??

Comment: @KJEjava48 you can use Firebase or any other cloud service. 
f.e. https://www.bitrise.io/blog/post/build-and-deploy-flutter-web-app-firebase